# Pandas replace function & "Returning a view versus a copy"

Tags: python, replace, pandas

I'm trying to use the replace function on my data frame, and I know that the problem is that I'm modifying a copy and should use `.loc` or `.ix` to return a view instead of a copy, but I'm a total beginner and struggled a bit with the pandas documentation on this.

I tried to do the following:

```
df.replace(df[(df.group_id=='12')]['clicks'], df2, inplace=True)
```

which just modifies a copy, and doesn't change the values in df.

I'm just not sure how I can use `.ix` in this case. I tried

```
df.replace(df[(df.group_id=='12')].ix[:,'clicks'], df2, inplace=True)
```

but that doesn't work.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did you try `df.ix[(df.group_id=='12'), 'clicks']`?

Comment: doesn't seem to work...

Comment: I'm not getting the "SettingWithCopy" error though...which is perhaps strange.

Comment: Try: `df.replace(df.loc[df.group_id=='12','clicks'],df2,inplace=True) `

Comment: @EdChum Why would you pass something other than a string/regex/`None` to `df.replace()` as the `to_replace` option? I can’t find why something like your suggestion (it’s like you think you’re passing in a selector?) should work when reading [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html).